# opencv 3.2 C++ VS2015 imshow access violation executing

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use the [sample](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) code to get image via the embedded camera of my laptop. I can get the image. But the **imshow** statement throw **Access violation executing**

Anyone can help me to figure out the reason?

Deeply appreciate!

Environment:  Visual Studio 2015, Opencv 3.2

c++ code:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cerr << "ERROR, unable to open the camera\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "start grapping" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        cap.read(frame);
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            cerr << "ERROR, blank frame grabbed \n";
            break;
        }

        // I added below statement to save the frame. 
        // check the frame from the camera.
        imwrite("D:\\CapturedImage.jpg", frame);

        // Below line throw Access violation executing location error
        imshow("Live", frame);
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be caused due to the absolute path "D:\\CapturedImage.jpg" that you've entered. Enter a relative path like "CapturedImage.jpg" and check

Comment: @SaranshKejriwal, Thanks for your reply. But it is not caused by that path.  that line works well. The error occurred at the line: `imshow("Live", frame)`, without the `imwrite("D:\\CapturedImage.jpg", frame)` line, also the same error. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. replace cap.read(frame); with cap>>frame;